# Tkiner Chatbot error with display a welcome message

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

i wanted to display a welcome message to the user. but I keep finding on the internet and cannot find anything similar to what I wanted to do. and also tried other method but still unable to do it

```
#Creating GUI with tkinter
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
def send():
    msg = EntryBox.get("1.0",'end-1c',).strip()
    EntryBox.delete("0.0",END)
    if msg != (''):
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "User: " + msg + '\n\n')
        ChatLog.config(foreground="#442265", font=("Verdana", 12 ))
        res = chatbot_response(msg)
        ChatLog.insert(END, "ITBot: " + res + '\n\n')
        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)
base = Tk()
base.title("Hello")
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
#Create Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white", height="8", width="50", font="Arial",)
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
#Bind scrollbar to Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="heart")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
#Create Button to send message
SendButton = Button(base, font=("Verdana",12,'bold'), text="Send", width="12", height=5,
                    bd=0, bg="#32de97", activebackground="#3c9d9b",fg='#ffffff',
                    command= send )
#Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, bg="white",width="29", height="5", font="Arial")
#EntryBox.bind("<Return>", send)
#Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376,y=6, height=386)
ChatLog.place(x=6,y=6, height=386, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=128, y=401, height=90, width=265)
SendButton.place(x=6, y=401, height=90)

  
base.mainloop()
```

Result i wanted is something like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWSVa.png)

Comment: From the posted code, you know how to insert text into the text box (inside `send()` function).  So what is the problem actually?

Comment: @acw1668 i cannot find a way post a welcome message. like when the user launch my application. I would like it to pop up a message "IT Bot : Welcome to my chatbot". sorry my English very bad

Comment: You can insert the welcome message right after creating the text box.